# Pandas Read CSV with string delimiters via regex

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas

I am trying to import a weirdly formatted text file into a pandas DataFrame. Two example lines are below:

```
LOADED LANE       1   MAT. TYPE=    2    LEFFECT=    1    SPAN=  200.    SPACE=   10.    BETA=   3.474 LOADEFFECT 5075.    LMAX= 3643.    COV=  .13
LOADED LANE       1   MAT. TYPE=    3    LEFFECT=    1    SPAN=  200.    SPACE=   10.    BETA=   3.515 LOADEFFECT10009.    LMAX= 9732.    COV=  .08
```

First I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('beta.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, usecols=[2,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19])
```

This seemed to work fine, however got messed up when it hit the above example line, where there is no whitespace after the `LOADEFFECT` string (you may need to scroll a bit right to see it in the example). I got a result like:

```
632   1   2   1  200  10  3.474  5075.  3643.  0.13
633   1   3   1  200  10  3.515  LMAX=   COV=   NaN
```

Then I decided to use a regular expression to define my delimiters. After many trial and error runs (I am no expert in regex), I managed to get close with the following line:

```
df = pd.read_csv('beta.txt', header=None, sep='/s +|LOADED LANE|MAT. TYPE=|LEFFECT=|SPAN=|SPACE=|BETA=|LOADEFFECT|LMAX=|COV=', engine='python')
```

This almost works, but creates a `NaN` column for some reason at the very beginning:

```
632 NaN  1  2  1  200  10  3.474   5075  3643  0.13
633 NaN  1  3  1  200  10  3.515  10009  9732  0.08
```

At this point I think I can just delete that first column, and get away with it. However I wonder what would be the correct way to set up the regex to correctly parse this text file in one shot. Any ideas? Other than that, I am sure there is a smarter way to parse this text file. I would be glad to hear your recommendations.

Thanks!

Comment: That looks more like a fixed-width format to me.  If you draw vertical lines in your file, does the data stay in the right columns?

Comment: `read_fwf` like DSM has mentioned can read this if the format is fixed-width, it accepts a `width` param where you can pass a list of each column width

Comment: @DSM yes, I think it is a fixed width format file.

Comment: @EdChum I didn't know about `read_fwf` I think that will fix my problem!

Comment: Also not sure but your initial issue may be related to line endings? "\r\n" vs "\n"

Comment: @dartdog The initial issue is related to one the values using the whole fixed width space allocated for it. The line with `LOADEFFECT10009.` messes up the "use whitespaces as delimiters" option in `read_csv`. EdChum's recommendation `read_fwf` works for now, as long as the files I have consistently have the same fixed width format..

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv
csvfile = open("parsing.txt") #open text file
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
new_list=[]
for line in reader:
    for i in line:
        new_list.append(re.findall(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', i))

table = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
table # output will be pandas DataFrame with values
```